# Is there a way to implement a "n-month" zoom-in/zoom-out in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, charts, svg, highcharts

I would like to implement a 1 month zoom-in and zoom-out on Highcharts, I've seen this functionality implemented on HighStock before but not on HighCharts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for the [minRange](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--minRange) option of the Axis you are zooming on.

> minRange : Number The minimum range to display on this axis. The
>   entire axis will not be allowed to span over a smaller interval than
>   this. For example, for a datetime axis the main unit is milliseconds.
>   If minRange is set to 3600000, you can't zoom in more than to one
>   hour.
>
> The default minRange for the x axis is five times the smallest
>   interval between any of the data points.